# Python packages blocked by group policy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-policy, applocker

I'm a new python developer and I'm trying to set it up on my work computer.

I'm able to install packages via pip after getting it unblocked. That was easy since it's just a .exe file for them to unblock.

I'm trying to use pandas/numpy and I get the error saying it was blocked by group policy. In the same program I import pypyodbc and it had no issues for some reason.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm having trouble pointing them to what to unblock. Do I point them to the site-packages folder and tell them to unblock the whole thing? None of them are developers and they do not service python so I have to point them to the information myself. I believe they use applocker.

Any information would be helpful. Thank you

Here is the error image from VSCode

[Error message from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbxvG.png)

Comment: If it is your job to develop using Python, than it is their job to unlock your work computer to allow that, even if they aren't "developers". If they can't do that, then they need to completely unlock your work computer so that you can, you know, work. Good luck.

Comment: @Flimm python development is not technically my job, but I work in an engineering/statistics heavy field with lots of cybersecurity concerns.

Comment: Well, I guess you run a Python debugger to try to figure out what the line that is causing the error is supposed to do, and what the values of the arguments `self._name` and `mode` are. I don't know much about Windows group policy, so I can't help you more than that.

Comment: I would recommend copying and pasting the error as text in the question, so that other users can find it easier, and maybe answer this question some day.

Comment: this is not a python issue:  contact the system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid and useful question for others in the same situation.

As some of the comments have already indicated, this is an administrators permission issue as opposed to being a `python` problem.

The solution would be to contact the system administrator to remove the group policy block.

Comment: I've just come across this question as I have pretty much the same issue.  We are a local gov, and the NCSC guidelines we need to meet if we want to keep our PSN accreditation means that applocker is enabled (and we will not be allowed to remove it).   Technically its not a Python issue, but how Windows does security, but the solution is not the remove the policy as most orgs will not be allowed to do that.  (I think we may have to go down the WSL route instead).